# The geometry of the mesh gets distorted when rigged and posed

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting, multiresolution

[image]

I tried to set up a rig into my character as you can see in the image. However, I have two problems :

A. When I move the rig, the geometry gets distorted crazy.

B. Whenever I move any joint, the pose mode lags so slow. All the joints do not bend as smooth as they are supposed to be in Youtube tutorials. Here are my approaches to the problem, which did not work :

1. Since the body mesh had 'Multiresolution' modifier on, I thought it was the excess number of geometry that is causing all the lagging and making the computer difficult to process. So I deleted the multires modifier and tried it with same rig. However, both the lagging or the crazy distortion of the model did not disappear.
2. I did not tried the weight painting method in rigging which most blender tutorial demonstrates, because just like the pose mode, the weight paint mode lags crazy. Maybe that is the problem, but I will give the description of how it looked when I entered weight painting mode: The character was in full dark blue with no red or green colours. Would there be any other approaches to solve this problem? By the way this is the tutorial that I followed : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TL45rxB30_o

Also, here is the file of my mesh : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1URSnA5C7Wp66RLt6UQEupGX9waX3DQpk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: hello, for the moment we need an authorization to download your file, please allow anyone  ;)

Comment: Sorry. I changed the setting. Is it working now?

Comment: yes it works but it makes my Blender crash, I hope someone will be able to help  ;)

Comment: Maybe because of different version? I am using 2.8.2.

Comment: or please tell me the exact name of the mesh object and armature object so that I can append them

Comment: Ok so the name of the body mesh is "bodyassembled.(backup)" in the body folder, and the armature object is named 'Armature" (It does not have a folder so you can find it straight away) Also, there are two body objects. So pick the first one.

Comment: So I deleted the Multires, because it's what make your computer lag, I applied the mesh scale, and recalculate its normals and it works fine

Comment: what does it mean by applying mesh scale? I know this might be a silly question but I am pretty new to blender.. so this might be the thing that I am missing out on. So deleting the multires and using mesh scale will make it work properly? Can I please have the files that you edited?

Comment: I meant the object scale: select the object in Object mode and press ctrl A (apply) > Scale. Here is the file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=xzYarSqw" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/xzYarSqw/)

Answer (score 1):

So to fix your problem:

- Disable the *Multiresolution* modifier, because it makes your computer lag (before parenting you need to bake the multires normals so that you can use a low-poly object instead).
- Apply the object scale with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Scale* (explanation about object scale [here](https://artisticrender.com/how-and-why-do-we-apply-scale-in-blender/)).
- In *Edit* mode select all and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate the normals.

To avoid parenting bugs it's always better to apply scale and rotation and to make sure that the normals are correctly flipped.

The file is [here](http://%5B%3Cimg%20src=%22https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=xzYarSqw%22%20/%3E%5D(https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/xzYarSqw/)).

Comment: Thank you so much. So it was the multires creating all this problem. But now my only concern is because I deleted the multires, I lost the body forms that I created with sculpting. How can I maintain this rig with the initial form that had the multires on? Should I consider retopology?

Comment: no it was not the Multires, the Multires made your computer lag, actually try to work with meshes as low-poly as possible. Before parenting, once you have sculpted your object with the Multires, bake the normals, so that you'll be able to use what you've sculpted as fake 3D, maybe follow a tutorial on this topic. Bad parenting was caused by the non-applied scale (rotation was applied) and the flipped normals.

Comment: Oh.. now I get it. When you mentioned non applied scale, did you mean the fact that I applied y+ axis align to all arm and leg bones? Maybe that was the part of the problem? Or is it simply me not using the mesh scale?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, you need to apply the object scale and rotation before parenting to avoid any bug, please click on the link I gave in my answer, or find any explanation on what are the object scale, rotation and location in Blender

Comment: Oh nevermind I think I thought kinda wrong.. I am now looking for tutorials on baking normals, and I found it is done to use a normal from high poly mesh to a low poly mesh to give it a similar effect and yet using a lot lower polygon. Is this what you are talking about? https://youtu.be/f1fynKtys-Y

Comment: yes exactly, you need to bake the high-poly to only use a low-poly

Comment: Ok great I will give it a try. Thank you again for all the help!